# How can i upload a picture in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9

i'm trying to insert a product with a picture into my database , but when i submit nothing get inserted .

i tried to add  'Image1' => 'required|Image' but i get *Unable to guess the MIME* error

This is the *Store method*

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $data = request()->validate([

            'Name' => 'required',
            'Title' => 'required',
            'category' => 'required',
            'MainPrice' => 'required',
            'MainPrice' => 'required',
            'StockQuantity' => 'required',
            'Discription' => 'required',
            'Features' => 'required',
            'Image1' => 'required'
    ]);



    $imagePath =request('Image1')->store('uploads', 'public');
    $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1200, 1200);
    $image ->save();


     $query = DB::table('products')->insert([



        'Name' => $request->input('Name'),
        'Title' =>  $request->input('Title'),
         'category' =>  $request->input('category'),
         'MainPrice' =>  $request->input('MainPrice'),
         'DiscountPrice' =>  $request->input('DiscountPrice'),
         'StockQuantity' =>  $request->input('StockQuantity'),
         'Discription'=>  $request->input('Discription'),
         'Features'=>  $request->input('Features'),
         'Image1'=> $imagePath

     ]) ;

     if($query){
         return back()->with('success', 'Data have been successfuly inserted');
     }
     else{
        return back()->with('fail', 'Somethimg went wrong');
     }
}
```

and this is the *Route*

```
Route::post('Product', [ProductsController::class, 'store']);
```

Any one faced the same problem ?

Comment: Why are you using `request()` helper when you are already type hinting `$request` as `store(Request $request)` method param? The issue is `$imagePath =request('Image1')->store('uploads', 'public');` . It should be `$request->file('Image1')->store('uploads', 'public');` `store()` is available on `UploadedFile` instance which is accessed by `$request->file('Image1')`.

Answer (score -1):

Your picture is probably in the wrong format. RTF is the most commonly used format, but it's not compatible with MySQL. You need an image format that supports transparency, such as GIF, JPG, or PNG.

Comment: RTF is not an image format, and JPG doesn't support transparency. And I'm not sure what you mean about RTF "not being supported by MySQL". Images aren't usually stored in databases—some kind of pointer _to_ the image is. If you really want to store the image itself, binary data is binary data. There's no reason that one image format would work while another doesn't.